# AVD stuck at logo screen

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Android AVD emulator Screen stuck up at start android logo and not progressing towards new screen. 
i have enables snapshot option in AVD configurations and but still its not progressing further.

I also installed **Genymotion** but it gave me blank screen which hang up the window.

please suggest me solution for this

[Stucked AVD screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J04TS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have installed all the required components for that api version. Also check the screen resolution if it is proper for the selected api version in avd.
If nothing works try deleting the avd and creating a fresh 1.